# Dijit form select

Tags: dojo

I have a question about the dgrid-master/editor_more_widgets.html test file on this path:

```
https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/test/editor_more_widgets.html
```

maybe you should download the whole package to see the file. anyway, is there a way to fix the "Select Store" column so it would show the label not the value, like the "FilteringSelect Store" column does?

Comment: you should make the title of your question more informative, and add more tags to your post, such as `javascript`, `dojo` and `dgrid`

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom plugin for this purpose. The key part is the renderCell function:

```
define([
    "dojo",
    "sb",
    "put-selector/put",
    "dgrid/editor",
    "dijit/form/Select"
], function(dojo, sb, put, editor, Select){
    dojo.global.starbug.grid.columns = dojo.global.starbug.grid.columns || {};
    dojo.global.starbug.grid.columns.select = function(column){

        //populate the cell with the label or value
        column.renderCell = function(object, value, cell, options, header){
            items = column.editorInstance.getOptions();
            for (var i in items) {
                if (value == items[i].value) value = items[i].label;
            }
            put(cell, 'span.'+value.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase(), value);
        };

        column.editorArgs = {
            style:'width:100%',
            labelAttr:'label',
            store:sb.get(column.from, 'select')
        };

        column = editor(column, Select, "dblclick");

        return column;
    };
});
```

Note that `sb` is a custom module I used to provide the store. You can modify it accordingly.